# Virtual memory size in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I got mongodb version 3.0 on linux redhat 6. The storage engine is MMAPv1.
I checked mongo memory usage on the server. I notice that virtual memory is 10 Gb which is far from mapped memory that is 4 Gb.
Is this situation correct or mongo server is running suboptimal?

Comment: Some answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/556889/mongod-non-mapped-virtual-memory-doubled-suddenly-has-not-changed-since/562442#562442) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/379802/mongodb-virtual-memory-usage)

Comment: see my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984824/linux-virtual-memory-too-large-and-how-is-it-decided.

Answer (score 0):

It should be related to the glibc new virtual memory management since glibc2.10.
see here .
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/linux_glibc_2_10_rhel_6_malloc_may_show_excessive_virtual_memory_usage?lang=en

In a nutshell, the new malloc will allocate by default 8*cores*64MB on 64bit system for thread memory pool.